# What is the minimum JQuery version for using Semantic-UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, semantic-ui

I'm using [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/) as a web front-end framework.

I noticed some problem with JQuery version below 1.8. I would like to know which is the inimum recommended version to use?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**EDIT:**
As per Agent_K, the minimum version required is v1.8.1

Though, I had recommended using the latest jQuery version at all times I did not consider the fact that the signatures would change when transitioning from jQuery 1 to jQuery 2.

I'd still recommend using jQuery 1.11 so that all bugs, would have been properly addressed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that does not answer the question at all. Just to say "take the latest version" is sort of too generic and does not actually add any clarification on the issue. Sometimes the circumstances demand a specific older jQuery version - e.g. when working under Wordpress which comes with 1.11.x only. Replacing the jQuery version in Wordpress sets you at risk breaking other plugins a user might have installed. So just loading the latest version could be a nightmare and lead to your plugin / theme being thrown out.

Comment: @Agent_K: Thanks! Updated.

Answer (score 3):

The bower.json of Semantic-UI (v1.8.1) defines jQuery 1.8 as minimum version.
Asking Jack Lukic about this issue he said:

- Semantic-UI Javascript is heavily based on promises, so jQuery >= 1.6
- a lot of components are heavily built on Transitions, so bugs in older jQuery version might compromise this.
- beyond that there seem to be no special issues with older jQuery versions.